# How can I perfectly center my image?

Tags: html, css, image, web, center

So I have an image on my website and I want to perfectly center it. I have tried many things but none have worked.

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: -5
}
```

```html
<img src="images/astronaut.png">
```

Comment: Centred vertically, horizontally or both? Can you provide more information about how it's meant to be displayed in the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: -5;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="images/astronaut.png">
```

The centering codes are the `left`, `top`, and especially the `transform`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to centre an image horizontally is with:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following links for further help, hope it helps.

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

```css
html { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background:url(http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.IX1fAIIUJ82DtdfgR2tSnADhEs&w=207&h=276&c=8&qlt=90&o=4&dpr=2&pid=1.7) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the left and right margin to auto will center the image horizontally within it's parent if your position isn't set or is set to relative.

So you could use:

```
img {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: -5
}
```

If your position needs to be set to absolute, you can use CSS3's viewport sizing to center your image. This would place the image in the exact center of the page; so if you want to center the image within a sidebar, for example, don't use this method. You'll need to set a width for your image and then align it using the "left" property. That would look like this:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: -5
  width: 500px;
  left: calc( 50vw - 250px );
}
```

The viewport is always 100vw wide, so setting the left property to 50vw - 1/2 of the image's width will center it on the page.

You can also use jQuery to similarly calculate the proper alignment and position the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in a div and make it 100% of the screen in width and height.
Then add text-align:center; to center it horizontally.
Then set the line height to 100% and then add vertical-align: middle; to the image to center it vertically.

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}

   .CenterImage img {

  height: 40%;
  z-index: -5;
vertical-align: middle;

}
.CenterImage{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
line-height: 100vh;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="CenterImage"><img src="images/astronaut.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -5
}
```

```html
<img src="images/astronaut.png">
```